# FragmentPagerAdapter android.support.v4.app.fragment can not be applied to android.ap.Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

First of all, I found hundred of question on this Topic and solution but none of them help me. because I m doing little different workaround.

FragmentPagerAdapter class constructor

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class HomePage_Slider extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public HomePage_Slider(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        MyArr.addAll(globalVariable.slider_image_url);
        mCount =MyArr.size();
    }

    public HomePage_Slider(android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }
 }
```

Fragment class

```
import android.app.Fragment;

public class host extends Fragment {
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_navigation_drawer, container, false);
         Top_slider = rootview.findViewById(R.id.home_slider_image);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) Top_slider.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new HomePage_Slider(getActivity().getFragmentManager()));
        }

}
```

I am using Navigation drawer using Support library and follow this tutorial  [Navigation Drawer Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) . and trying to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` to display slider.  and My Host Fragment class uses `import android.app.Fragment;` and FragmentPagerAdapter class uses `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Because of My host Fragment class do not import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
FragmentPagerAdapter constructor giving error **FragmentPagerAdapter android.support.v4.app.fragment can not be applied to android.ap.Fragment**

while searching solution I found this changing my import will do the trick but my rest app will stop working. used `import android.app.Fragment;` to do other work like calling other Fragment class transaction something like this

```
//Host Fragment have this code  to swap to next Fragment on click event on listview
 ((MainActivity)getActivity()).category_product_page();

  // class contains 
  MainActivity.java 

// go to wishlist page
    public void category_product_page() {
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        cart_product newFragment = new cart_product ();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

and I also did some other work on host Fragment that's why I can not change  `import android.app.Fragment "` to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
any suggestion  will be helpful.

Please suggest how can I overcome this error and prevent these error in future as my second app have slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***FragmentPagerAdapter android.support.v4.app.fragment can not be applied to android.ap.Fragment***

> When you are using android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager then you
>   should use getSupportFragmentManager() and if you are using
>   android.app.FragmentManager then call getFragmentManager()

You are using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

**Don't**

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(new HomePage_Slider(getActivity().getFragmentManager()));
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

**Do**

```
     viewPager.setAdapter(new HomePage_Slider(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

You should call **`getSupportFragmentManager ()`** instead of **`getFragmentManager()`** .

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
>   with this activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager()
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

After that use

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

where you are using

```
getFragmentManager()
```

**Note:** Anywher you get error simply use support import statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use 2 different libraries for same thing. You should use v4.app or app.Fragment for your all fragments and fragment managers to get working result.